# Windows 7 can't copy file - Error 0x800700DF: The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved

Tags: windows, samba, file-transfer, openfiler

Any attempt to copy files larger than about 40 MB from a network share (a SAN running open filer / Samba) to my local machine running Windows 7 always results in the following error and the copy fails:

Error 0x800700DF: The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved.

I've tried copying to my C: drive and a USB drive with the same results. Smaller files copy just fine. Clearly 40 MB is not that big of a file so I'm assuming it is some buggy interaction between windows 7 and Samba perhaps. Google has so far turned up nothing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

We recently upgraded OpenFiler/Samba on the file server and I can now happily report that I was able to copy a 3GB file with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything on that error either... Does this happen with any other computers in your network?  Grasping at straws here, but I'd recommend capturing a network trace during the file copy operation with Netmon or WireShark and compare them with a trace of the operation working on another client, and see if any difference in the traffic jumps out at you.

Comment: I am able to copy large files from other linux/samba boxes on the network. I'll try wireshark if I don't make any headway.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and it seems to have disappeared -- maybe the most recent Win7 patch?  Have you tested this in the last few days with a fully-updated system?

Answer (score 0):

A similar error may be seen when WebDAV is used to download files from shares that look like samba but are not. It this case you may need to apply a registry fix to the HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\FileSizeLimitInBytes key and restart WebClient service.

See for example http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900900